# How Do You Configure IBM Worklight Studio to Build for ARM and MIPS devices?

Tags: android, arm, mips, ibm-mobilefirst, abi

I'm using Worklight Studio Developer Edition plugin for the Eclipse IDE Juno JAVA EE to test building hybrid apps and I'm trying to build and deploy to an Android MIPS based device.  ARM devices and emulators work fine but the MIPS device will not install.

I receive the following errors from the console and logcat.

[2013-03-05 00:27:36 - Project1App1Android] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2013-03-05 00:27:36 - Project1App1Android] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-03-05 00:27:36 - Project1App1Android] Launch canceled!

03-05 00:28:18.607: W/PackageManager(90): Native ABI mismatch from package file

I think the problem is the build is not including MIPS support for older device SDKs like Froyo 2.2.1 which is on the devce I'm having problems with. How can I configure Worklight to build for ARM and older MIPS? I have the MDS Eclipse plugin for PhoneGap installed as well and it builds and deploys to the same MIPS device without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Android applications are built and run with help of Android Development Tools. The unified support for all processor architectures is included in Release 21 of Android SDK. You can read the announcement here: [Official Android SDK](http://developer.mips.com/2012/11/01/official-android-sdk-now-with-full-mips-support/), [Installation instructions](http://developer.mips.com/android/download-android-sdk/)

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply and reference links. I already have the Android SDK Tools Rev 21.1 installed but I'm targeting an MIPS Android 2.2.1 device that does not have a MIPS image in the SDK. Android SDK v21+ states full MIPS support for Jelly Bean 4.2 ABI 17, Jelly Bean 4.1 ABI 16 and Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3 ABI 15. I've changed my uses-sdk to target 9, min 8, max 17 as MIPS integrated support requires target 9 Android 2.3.  http://http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html  So, is there a separate process for MIPS support on devices using older Android SDKs?

Comment: Thanks all! I decided to deploy the open source MEAP Convertigo on OpenShift or Azure Paas.

Answer (score 0):

This is outside of the Worklight scope. You should open the Android SDK Manager, and make sure to install any support by Google related to MIPS and/or ARM.

The generated .apk is generated via Google's Android Developer Tools.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I have ADT v21.1 installed which supports MIPS for newer Android SDKs, (Thanks @vitalym), but I'm targeting a device with an SDK of Android 2.2.1 which does not have the new MIPS support in the SDK. I think I need to setup MIPS support for older SDKs because I tried a Jelly Bean 4.2+ emulator with MIPS and ARM processors and the app installed and ran.  So it seems like my problem is older Android targets.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks all! I decided to deploy the open source MEAP Convertigo on OpenShift or Azure Paas.